# Unable to display product images on the frontend of my Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2

Hello Magento community,

I am having an issue with my Magento 2.4.2 store where product images are not displayed on the frontend after importing products from ChannelAdvisor. The images are visible in the backend and on the individual product pages, but on the frontend main page, they are replaced with Magento's default placeholder images.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
Checked the image file permissions in the media folder and set them to 777 using the command chmod -R 777 media/.
Changed the Magento theme to see if it was an issue with the specific theme, but the problem persisted across different themes.
Checked the URLs of the images on the frontend, and they pointed to the default placeholder image URLs like this one: https://toptrending-products.com/static/frontend/presiden/presiden_cosmetics_home1/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
Verified that the media folder's path is correct in Magento 2.
Reindexed the database using the command bin/magento indexer:reindex and cleared the image cache using bin/magento catalog:image:resize.
```

Despite trying all these steps, the product images still don't appear on the frontend main page. It's worth mentioning that I am importing products from ChannelAdvisor, and the images display correctly in the backend and on the individual product pages.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance!

What I tried:

```
Checked the image file permissions in the media folder and set them to 777 using the command chmod -R 777 media/.
Changed the Magento theme to see if it was an issue with the specific theme, but the problem persisted across different themes.
Checked the URLs of the images on the frontend, and they pointed to the default placeholder image URLs like this one: https://toptrending-products.com/static/frontend/presiden/presiden_cosmetics_home1/en_US/Magento_Catalog/images/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg
Verified that the media folder's path is correct in Magento 2.
Reindexed the database using the command bin/magento indexer:reindex and cleared the image cache using bin/magento catalog:image:resize.
```

Expected results:

I expected the product images to be displayed correctly on the frontend main page after importing the products from ChannelAdvisor and trying the above steps.

Actual results:

Despite trying all these steps, the product images still don't appear on the frontend main page. The images are replaced with Magento's default placeholder images.

It's worth mentioning that I am importing products from ChannelAdvisor, and the images display correctly in the backend and on the individual product pages.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance!